# Counting significant figures in a number

Tags: python, fixed-point

I decided to make something to count the significant figures in a number to see how easily it could be done, but I think there may have been a better or simpler way. Any advice even just for conventional purposes is appreciated!

```
def count_sig_figs(answer):
    '''This fucntion will count the sigfigs used in the answer of a user'''
    sig_fig_count = 0
    num_list = list(answer)

    for index in range(len(num_list)):
        try:
            fig = int(num_list[index])
            if fig != 0:
                sig_fig_count +=1
            elif check_zero_sig(index, num_list, sig_fig_count):
                sig_fig_count += 1
        except:
            continue
    return sig_fig_count

def check_zero_sig(index, num_list, sig_fig_count):
    '''Checks for significance in a zero from a list'''
    try:
        decimal = num_list.index('.')
        if index > decimal and sig_fig_count > 0:
            return True
    except:
        if index == 0:
            return False
        elif index == len(num_list):
            return False
        new_index = index+1

        if num_list[new_index] == '.' and sig_fig_count > 0:
            return True
        elif num_list[new_index] == '.' and sig_fig_count == 0:
            return False
        elif num_list[new_index] != '.' and sig_fig_count > 0:
            fig = int(num_list[new_index])
            if fig != 0:
                return True
            else:
                return check_zero_sig(new_index, num_list, sig_fig_count)
        elif num_list[new_index] != '.' and sig_fig_count == 0:
            fig = int(num_list[new_index])
            if fig != 0:
                return True
            else:
                return check_zero_sig(new_index, num_list, sig_fig_count)
        else:
            return False

def test():
    print(count_sig_figs('1')) # 1 sig fig
    print(count_sig_figs('10')) # 1 sig fig
    print(count_sig_figs('100')) # 1 sig fig
    print(count_sig_figs('1004')) # 4 sig figs
    print(count_sig_figs('10004')) # 5 sig figs
    print(count_sig_figs('105')) # 3 sig figs
    print(count_sig_figs('01')) # 1 sig fig
    print(count_sig_figs('1.2035')) # 5 sig figs
    print(count_sig_figs('001.09508')) # 6 sig figs
    print(count_sig_figs('0.00110')) # 3 sig figs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Comment: Only needs one of [tag:python] [tag:python-3.x] -- it seems like this works in 2 as well as 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num_list` is better named `digits`; don't describe the *type*, describe the *value*.

`test`'s output is unhelpful; the result should be much more obvious, especially when it fails. Keeping along the given lines, I might do something like

```
def test():
    def should_be(string, count):
        assert count_sig_figs(string) == count
        print("{!r} has {} sf.".format(string, count))

    should_be('1', 1)
    should_be('10', 1)
    should_be('100', 1)
    should_be('1004', 4)
    should_be('10004', 5)
    should_be('105', 3)
    should_be('01', 1)
    should_be('1.2035', 5)
    should_be('001.09508', 6)
    should_be('0.00110', 3)
```

Of course, a proper test suite is probably better.

This isn't idiomatic:

```
for index in range(len(digits)):
    try:
        fig = int(digits[index])
        if fig != 0:
            sig_fig_count +=1
        elif check_zero_sig(index, digits, sig_fig_count):
            sig_fig_count += 1
    except:
        continue
return sig_fig_count
```

Bare `try...except`s are **bad**. Even

```
except (ValueError, IndexError):
```

is bad. Primarily this is because you're spreading out the checks where they don't belong and it should instead be

```
try:
    fig = int(digits[index])
except ValueError:
    continue

if fig != 0:
    sig_fig_count +=1
else:
    try:
        zero_sig = check_zero_sig(index, digits, sig_fig_count)
    except IndexError:
        continue
    if zero_sig:
        sig_fig_count += 1
```

But then because... *why* is `check_zero_sig` throwing an `IndexError`? Surely that's a bug.

Before we get there, quickly change this to

```
for index, digit in enumerate(digits):
    if digit == ".":
        continue
    if digit != '0':
        sig_fig_count += 1
    else:
        sig_fig_count += check_zero_sig(index, digits, sig_fig_count)
```

That's pretty much what we want expressed more simply.

`check_zero_sig`'s `except` also needs updating:

```
try:
    decimal = digits.index('.')
except ValueError:
    ...
else:
    return index > decimal and sig_fig_count > 0
```

I don't get why you don't just mutate `index` instead of using `new_index`.

This can be simplified:

```
if digits[index] == '.' and sig_fig_count > 0:
    return True
elif digits[index] == '.' and sig_fig_count == 0:
    return False
```

to

```
if digits[index] == '.':
    return bool(sig_fig_count)
```

The

```
elif digits[index] != '.' and sig_fig_count > 0:
```

and

```
elif digits[index] != '.' and sig_fig_count == 0:
```

branches are the same.

This then simplifies to

```
if digits[index] == '.':
    return bool(sig_fig_count)
elif digits[index] != '.':
    digit = int(digits[index])
    return bool(digit) or check_zero_sig(index, digits, sig_fig_count)
else:
    return False
```

which is just

```
if digits[index] == '.':
    return bool(sig_fig_count)
else:
    digit = int(digits[index])
    return bool(digit) or check_zero_sig(index, digits, sig_fig_count)
```

Then we see

```
elif index == len(digits):
    return False
```

cannot fire until *after* `index += 1`. This lets us fix our `IndexError`.

Back to `count_sig_figs`. The documentation is not written idiomatically. Documentation should be to the point, direct and not talk in third person.

```
def count_sig_figs(digits):
    '''Return the number of significant figures of the input digit string'''
    sig_fig_count = 0
    for index, digit in enumerate(digits):
        if digit == ".":
            continue
        if digit != '0':
            sig_fig_count += 1
        else:
            sig_fig_count += check_zero_sig(index, digits, sig_fig_count)
    return sig_fig_count
```

Back to `check_zero_sig`, which is now

```
def check_zero_sig(index, digits, sig_fig_count):
    '''Checks for significance in a zero from a list'''
    try:
        decimal = digits.index('.')
    except ValueError:
        if index == 0:
            return False
        index += 1
        if index == len(digits):
            return False
        if digits[index] == '.':
            return bool(sig_fig_count)
        else:
            digit = int(digits[index])
            return bool(digit) or check_zero_sig(index, digits, sig_fig_count)
    else:
        return index > decimal and sig_fig_count > 0
```

The `if digits[index] == '.'` check can't fire; we're in the `except`. Then

```
digit = int(digits[index])
return bool(digit) or check_zero_sig(index, digits, sig_fig_count)
```

can be

```
return digit != '0' or check_zero_sig(index, digits, sig_fig_count)
```

and the recursion, which would end up re-calling `.index`, can just be

```
if index == 0:
    return False
return any(digit != '0' for digit in digits[index+1:])
```

`index == 0` is a very strange special case; you deal with `01` but not `001` or `00001`. I suggest removing the special-case and using `sig_fig_count`.

Now we have

```
def check_zero_sig(index, digits, sig_fig_count):
    '''
    Returns if a zero digit at a given position is significant,
    given a count of significant digits preceding it.
    '''
    if not sig_fig_count:
        return False
    try:
        decimal = digits.index('.')
    except ValueError:
        return any(digit != '0' for digit in digits[index+1:])
    else:
        return index > decimal
```

Most of this complexity is avoidable by using string operations and splitting cases:

```
def count_sig_figs(digits):
    '''Return the number of significant figures of the input digit string'''

    integral, _, fractional = digits.partition(".")

    if fractional:
        return len((integral + fractional).lstrip('0'))
    else:
        return len(integral.strip('0'))
```

That's the entirety of the logic!

Another test case you should consider is `100.`. Does that have 1 significant figure or 3?

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much this was very helpful. It wasn't until just recently that I thought about that last test case and the way you compacted the is great. I will implement these changes and work on understanding all of the changes.

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternative Solution with Regular Expressions

```
def count_sig_figs(answer):
    str_answer = str(answer).replace('.', '')
    m = re.match( r'[1-9](\d*[1-9])?', str_answer)
    return len(m.group())
```

Note while the regex works perfectly in RegexBuddy (set to python), I had issues getting this to run at the command line.

The regex looks for a non-zero digit (1-9), followed by an optional grouping of [any digits (0-9) AND a final non-zero digit (1-9)]. Any match will be the significant digits.  Getting the length of the match returns the number of significant digits.

Also note that in your example, the last entry appears to have two significant digits, but you have it listed as three in the comment:  `print(count_sig_figs('0.00110')) # 3 sig figs`

Comment: yes if you have a number such as .01 that is one sigfig, but a number like .010 is 2 because you have shown that the uncertainty lies in the thousandth's place not in the hundredth's place. so the last result should be 3 sigfigs because the last 0 is from the precision of your measurements

Comment: It's been too long since I've done significant figures then.  The regex will need to be reworked then, to handle trailing zeros after a decimal point.  I think it can still be done but I'll have to think on it some more.